# Сравнение двух коллекций по определенному полю

Tags: java

Есть две коллекции `List`:

```
List<QBalances> qBalancesList
List<Coefficient> coefficientList
```

В списках лежат объекты `Coefficient`:

```
private Integer idCoefficient;
private String article;
private String titleArticle;
private Double coef;
```

и `QBalances`:

```
private Integer idQBalance;
private String qArticle;
private String qTitleArticle;
private Double qQuantity;
```

Мне нужно сравнить поля `article` и `qArticle`.

Цикл для сверки полей:

```
public List countingPiecesInSquareMeters() {
    List<QBalances> qBalancesList = this.getQBalancesList();
    List<Coefficient> coefficientList = this.getCoefficientsList();
    List<QBalancesSquareMeters> list = new ArrayList<QBalancesSquareMeters>();
    for (Coefficient coefficient : coefficientList) {
        for (QBalances qbalances : qBalancesList) {
            if (coefficient.getArticle().equals(qbalances.getqArticle())) {
                QBalancesSquareMeters squareMeters = new QBalancesSquareMeters();
                squareMeters.setArticle(qbalances.getqArticle());
                squareMeters.setTitleArticle(qbalances.getqTitleArticle());
                squareMeters.setSquareMeters(qbalances.getqQuantity() * coefficient.getCoef());
                list.add(squareMeters);
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Как переписать цикл так, чтобы сравнение происходило либо до первого совпадения (если есть совпадение, то выполняется блок `if` и берётся поле следующего объекта для сверки), либо (если совпадений не будет во всей коллекции) выполняется какой-то метод блока `else`.
То есть как сделать так, чтобы при первом несовпадении не выполнялся сразу блок `else`, а продолжалась сверка до конца коллекции, и только после этого выполнился `else`, если нет совпадений?

Comment: Создаете булевый флаг, по умолчанию ложь. в вашей ветке if  присваиваете флагу истину, и по завершению цикла, если флаг ложь, выполняете  вашу ветку "else"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поиск до первого совпадения (`squareMeters`) и обработка случая, если совпадение не найдено:

```
QBalancesSquareMeters squareMeters = null;
for (Coefficient coefficient : coefficientList)
{
    for (QBalances qbalances : qBalancesList)
    {
        if (coefficient.getArticle().equals(qbalances.getqArticle()))
        {
            squareMeters = new QBalancesSquareMeters();
            squareMeters.setArticle(qbalances.getqArticle());
            //squareMeters.setTitleArticle(qbalances.getqTitleArticle());
            //squareMeters.setSquareMeters(qbalances.getqQuantity() * coefficient.getCoef());
            break;
        }
    }
    if (squareMeters != null)
    {
        break;
    }
}
if (squareMeters == null)
{
    System.out.println("Not found");
}
```

За остановку сравнения отвечают два `break`-a, по одному на каждый цикл, а за обработку отсутствия совпадения - `if (squareMeters == null)` в конце кода.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, что нужно заменить внутренний if

```
    return getCoefficientsList().stream()
        .map(coefficient -> {
            return getQBalancesList().stream()
                .filter(balance -> balance.getqArticle().equals(coefficient.getArticle()))
                .map(balance -> {
                    QBalancesSquareMeters entry = new QBalancesSquareMeters();
                    entry.setArticle(qbalances.getqArticle());
                    entry.setTitleArticle(qbalances.getqTitleArticle());
                    entry.setSquareMeters(qbalances.getqQuantity() * coefficient.getCoef());
                    return entry;
                })
                .findFirst()
                // вместо null можно подставить свое значение, которое будет 
                // использоваться, если для данного коэффициента не нашлось 
                // подходящего баланса
                .orElse(null);
        })
        .collect(Collectiors.toList());
}
```

Проверять не проверял, но вроде все должно быть ок. С учетом того, что эти данные наверняка прилетают из классической реляционной базы данных, возможно, имеет смысл положиться на джойн-запрос и упростить себе задачу.